# Change menu button based on menu visibility (menu state)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.kirupa.com/react/smooth_sliding_menu_react_motion.htm

I have the functionality of menu working -- it slides in and out based on clicking on my button, however the face of the button won't change. I'm using FontAwesome, trying to switch from `fas fa-bars fa-2x` when the menu is not visible, to `fas fa-times fa-2x` when it is visible. I don't know why the icons aren't changing on the click.

In the code below I've added a character in the enclosing "open/close" button divs, and they alternate as expected, so I know the state is changing and is being monitored. But why won't fontAwesome content change as well?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Social from '../Elements/Social';
import Menu from './Menu';


export default class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    }

    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);

  }

  handleMouseDown(e) {
    this.toggleMenu();

    console.log("clicked");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.setState({
      visible: !this.state.visible
    });
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div className="site-nav--cntr">
        <div className="site-nav--btns">
          <Link className="site-nav-btn--cntr" to={"/"}>
            <div className="site-nav--btn site-nav-logo">VR</div>
          </Link>

          <div className="site-nav--btn site-nav-trigger open"
            onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
            menuVisibility={this.state.visible}
            >

            {
              (!this.state.visible) ?
                (<div className="hello"><i className="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>h</div>
                ) :
                (<div className="goodbye"><i className="fas fa-times fa-2x"></i>g</div>)
            }


          </div>

        </div>

        <Menu
          handleMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
          menuVisibility={this.state.visible} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind setting up this up on codesandbox.io? I think your problem may be outside the code you pasted above.